# How to update FQDN for gitlab after installation

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-clone

I've installed gitlab eight months ago, so far everything works very fine.

Recently I have changed the domaine name of our agency website (from agency.com to newagancy.com), so I would like to change also gitlab domaine name. (from gitlab.agency.com to gitlab.newagency.com)

I have made some changes in two config files:

- /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
- /home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml

But I still dont have my gitlab working with new domaine name in ssh and http cloning urls, even if the command :

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

shows this :

```
GitLab information
Version:    6.7.2
Revision:   dbbf4ea
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://gitlab.newagency.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.newagency.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.newagency.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no
```

Certainly I have missed some thing, but I can't figure it out,

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: I think you will also have to update the nginx configuration to reflect the change.

Specifically, `server_name` directive if you are using nginx.

Comment: I'm using plesk width apache and nginx only for server-proxy, so I cant do this tip.

By the the way, to redirect user requests to gitlab public dir, I have used passenger module to performe this.

Comment: I want to say : reverse-proxy, not server-proxy sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Check if you followed the all the steps at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#6-nginx, you probably have to:

*Change YOUR_SERVER_FQDN to the fully-qualified domain name of your host serving GitLab.*

`sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab
sudo service nginx restart`

I found the solution to many issues searching on https://about.gitlab.com/getting-help/, for future issues.